# Why is this catch block not catching the thrown exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I have this code:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Thrower();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("exception caught");
    }
}
```

Which calls this method:

```
private void Thrower()
{
    throw new OverflowException();
}
```

Well I'm not very experienced when it comes to exception handling, but I would have thought that this message box ("exception caught") would show here. It doesn't. Should it be? If not, what am I doing wrong? Have I misunderstood how this is supposed to work?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you clicking the button? Have you ensured the event handler is hooked-up?

Comment: Are you actually creating and throwing your own `OverflowException`, or are you expecting a line of code to throw it for you? Perhaps the operation isn't actually overflowing? Perhaps you're not operating in a `checked` context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested this and it works fine for me.  Are you sure you sure the `btn1_Click` method is actually being called? Maybe you forgot to wire up your events?

Comment: It was... embarrassing. I can only thank you for your time and decry my own stupidity.

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint inside your try/catch to see if it's even getting in there (It's not)

Comment: Or add MessageBox.Show("Just before Thrower();"); before Thrower();